# How To Secure Hidden Id When Post The Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hidden-field

I have a form And when the user submits the data,
I want to secure the hidden field that he can't change the id "value".

Comment: Post some code and explain what you have done please.

Comment: You can't.  The client can post whatever data it wants to the server.  Always, ***always*** validate the authentication/authorization of the request server-side.

Comment: you can encrypt your id and decrypt it in controller

Comment: @HienNguyen How i can encrypt my id and decrypt it

Comment: you can use https://github.com/brix/crypto-js

Comment: @hien just to confirm - you do realize that encrypting value client doesn’t help here at all?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ...  I created a new class contains 2 methods " encrypt, decrypt " and use it in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to prevent user from hacking client side information.

If you have something that is generated by server side code then you can either save that information in server side state (for example using asp.net session state) or encrypt server side so client can’t tamper with it and only can post it back (don’t forget to verify and see if replay is a problem).

Note that no amount of client side encryption would help as user can simply run the same code to produce values as if your client side code did that.

Comment: I use a encrypt id in server side and pass it value to the client, then I decrypt the id when he posts back to the server...